Calculating specific measures of lists using polars
I have a dataframe in polars that look like this
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "foo": [3, 4, 6],
    "bar_list": [[62, 40, 20], [10, 9, 8, 7], [20, 15, 12, 10, 8, 5]]
})

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬────────────────────────┐
│ foo ┆ bar_list               │
│ --- ┆ ---                    │
│ i64 ┆ list[i64]              │
╞═════╪════════════════════════╡
│ 3   ┆ [62, 40, 20]           │
│ 4   ┆ [10, 9, 8, 7]          │
│ 6   ┆ [20, 15, 12, 10, 8, 5] │
└─────┴────────────────────────┘

where foo is the number of elements in the bar list, which is sorted by value from highest to lowest. This list can be thought of as a frequency list
The function that I want to implement is as follows:
import math

def get_custom(list_of_frequencies):

    median_freq=math.floor(sum(list_of_frequencies)/2)
    running_total=0
    counter=0

    while running_total <= median_freq:
        running_total+= list_of_frequencies[counter]
        counter+= 1
    
    return round(counter+(1-(running_total-median_freq)/list_of_frequencies[counter-1]),2)

Which in pandas, I would call using .apply()
df.to_pandas()['bar_list'].apply(get_custom)

0    1.98
1    2.78
2    3.00
Name: bar_list, dtype: float64

How would I do this in polars?
Note: I am using polars version 0.18.4 due to some limitations.

Hello Tim, as mentioned in the original post, "This list can be thought of as a frequency list". I also termed it as the median element, rather than the median. So I am not computing the median, and I did not say I was computing the median.

I also don’t follow your calculation. Could you provide a function computing what you consider the median element for any regular (python) list? Then, it’d be easier to suggest a idiomatic solution in polars.

Well, the computation is clear enough; me = sum(xlist)/2, but I don't know how you go from 17 to median element being 2.  That's not clear at all.

Please provide the code for your Pandas custom function so the logic is clear.

I have edited the problem to remove using terms like "median element" where the definition is unclear. Instead, I have provided a function which describes what I want to implement

.list.eval() can be used to run expressions on list elements.
It seems like your logic translates to finding the first index where cum_sum > median_freq
Porting your function over to Polars Expressions could look something like:
def get_custom_expr(col):
    median_freq = (pl.element().sum() / 2).floor()
    counter = (pl.element().cum_sum() > median_freq).arg_true().first() + 1
    running_total = pl.element().head(counter).sum()
    
    return (
        col.list.eval(
            (counter+(1-(running_total-median_freq)/pl.element().get(counter-1)))
              .round(2)
        )
        .list.first()
    )

.pipe() can be a useful way to call custom functions that generate expressions.
df.with_columns(
    pl.col('bar_list').pipe(get_custom_expr).alias('result')
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬────────────────────────┬────────┐
│ foo ┆ bar_list               ┆ result │
│ --- ┆ ---                    ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ list[i64]              ┆ f64    │
╞═════╪════════════════════════╪════════╡
│ 3   ┆ [62, 40, 20]           ┆ 1.98   │
│ 4   ┆ [10, 9, 8, 7]          ┆ 2.78   │
│ 6   ┆ [20, 15, 12, 10, 8, 5] ┆ 3.0    │
└─────┴────────────────────────┴────────┘

